# How to put a image from mysql databases (mysql workbench)

Tags: php, mysql, image, mysql-workbench

I have an image with type BLOB but I can't see the image. I see a rare picture:

[image: rare picture]

Here is my code:

```
<?php
   include "includes/bootstrap.php";
   include "includes/connexio_web.php";
   obrirConnexioBD();
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Llistat_vies ";
   $sth = $conn->query($sql);
   $result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
   echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( 
   $result['foto_via'] ).'"/>';
?>
```

Comment: *but doesn't work* is not an error description

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I added a picture , thank's.

Comment: We don't need a picture, we need to know what's in the DB. Things like what kind of data type is `foto_via`?

Comment: It's type BLOB.

Comment: And how did you populate the BLOB field?